# Google Snap to Roads

Tags: google-maps

I have a set of lat long in my database and i wanted to display them on a map connected/drawn together by a line following the road. Some of the lat long i have in my database aren't on the road but i wanted them to view on a road connected together like a tracking app.

My code displays the lats longs(coordinates) but doesnt follow the road or the coordinates are not snapped on the roads.

Here's my code:

```
`function initialize() {

 @foreach($track as $transac)
    lati = {{$transac->latitude}}; 
    lngi = {{$transac->longitude}};
  @endforeach

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: lati, lng: lngi}
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var locate = [
@foreach($transactions as $location)
        ['{{ $location->address }}<br> {{ $location->details }}', {{ $location->latitude }}, {{ $location->longitude }}],   
@endforeach
];

var alltransaction = [
@foreach($alltransactions as $location)
        ['{{ $location->address }}<br> {{ $location->details }}', {{ $location->latitude }}, {{ $location->longitude }}],   
@endforeach
];

  var marker, i;

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati,lngi),
  map: map,
  icon: 'images/car.jpg'
  });

runSnapToRoad();

}

// Snap a user-created polyline to roads and draw the snapped path
function runSnapToRoad() {
  var pathValues = [];
  var pathVal = [];
  var pathcon = [];
  var utime;

  @foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    utime = '{{$transaction->updated_at}}';
  @endforeach


  @foreach($track as $transac)
    if('{{$transac->updated_at}}' < utime)
      pathVal.push("{{$transac->latitude}},{{$transac->longitude}}")
    else 
       pathValues.push("{{$transac->latitude}},{{$transac->longitude}}"); 
  @endforeach
 pathcon.push(pathVal[pathVal.length-1]);
 pathcon.push(pathValues[0]);
alert(pathcon);
  $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
    interpolate: true,
    key: apiKey,
    path: pathValues.join('|')
  }, function(data) {
    processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
    drawSnappedPolyline();
  });

}

// Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road method.
function processSnapToRoadResponse(data) {
snappedCoordinates = [];
placeIdArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
placeIdArray.push(data.snappedPoints[i].placeId);
  }
}

// Draws the snapped polyline (after processing snap-to-road response).
function drawSnappedPolyline() {
  var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: snappedCoordinates,
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
  polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
}

$(window).load(initialize);

setInterval(function myfunction()
{
  $('#btn').click();
}, 1000000);`
```

Answer (score 1):

If some of your lat/long are not snapped to the road, it could indicate that points are too far apart from each other.

> [Roads demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo): “The snapping algorithm works best for points that are close together. If you observe odd snapping behaviour, try creating paths that have points closer together.”

I got best results when points are within 400m apart from each other. This helps to interpolate the path between them and to lie the polyline on top of the road.

Btw: [the roads inspector](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/full/inspector_with_api_key) is handy for inspecting lat/long data.